# Video recording in Android only record video just ONCE

Tags: android

I found this working code that will capture a video and modified a bit. Yes, the code is working well, but it only allows the user to record a video just ONCE.  When the user tap the "Stop Recording" in the menu the moment I tap the "Start Recording" it will no longer record a video again.

What I want to happen is when I tap "Stop Recording" it will prepare the camera again then when I tap "Start Recording" it will record a new video.

How to fix this problem?

Here the main code by the way:

```
package com.tcs.video; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;

public class VideoRecorder extends Activity{

private MediaRecorder recorder;
private Preview mPreview;

boolean flag=false; 
boolean startedRecording=false;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    mPreview = new Preview(VideoRecorder.this,recorder);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(mPreview);

}


@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.clear(); 
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Start Recording"); 
    menu.add(1, 1, 0, "Stop Recording");

    menu.setGroupVisible(0, false);
    menu.setGroupVisible(1, false);

    if(startedRecording==false){
        menu.setGroupVisible(0, true);
        menu.setGroupVisible(1, false);
    }else if(startedRecording==true){
        menu.setGroupVisible(1, true);
        menu.setGroupVisible(0, false);
    }

    return true;
}


 /*!
    <p>
    This method receives control when Item in menu option is selected. It contains implementations
    to be performed on selection of menu item. 
    </p>*/

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
    case 0:
        //start the recorder
        recorder.start();
        startedRecording=true;
        break;

    case 1: 
        //stop the recorder
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
        startedRecording=false;
        break;


    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    //Create objects for MediaRecorder and SurfaceHolder.
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    MediaRecorder tempRecorder;

    //Create constructor of Preview Class. In this, get an object of 
    //surfaceHolder class by calling getHolder() method. After that add   
    //callback to the surfaceHolder. The callback will inform when surface is 
    //created/changed/destroyed. Also set surface not to have its own buffers.
    public Preview(Context context,MediaRecorder recorder) {
        super(context);
        tempRecorder=recorder;
        mHolder=getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Surface getSurface()
    {
        return mHolder.getSurface();
    }

    // Implement the methods of SurfaceHolder.Callback interface

    // SurfaceCreated : This method gets called when surface is created.
    // In this, initialize all parameters of MediaRecorder object.
    //The output file will be stored in SD Card.

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
        tempRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/recordvideooutput.3gpp");
        tempRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());
        try{
            tempRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String message = e.getMessage();
            tempRecorder.release();
            tempRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        if(tempRecorder!=null)
        {
            tempRecorder.release();
            tempRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) 
    {

    }
    }   
}
```

Please help!

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 0):

When you press the Stop button, it releases the recorder and assigns it to null. Unless there's something I'm not seeing here, there's nothing to prepare it again for another recording.

Try using `recorder.reset()` instead of `release()` and `= null`. There's a good explanation of the life cycle in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot... I'll try this one at home. :)

Comment: Hello Geobits, I tried your recommendation, but still its not working. :(

Comment: Please see post above Geobits

Comment: You can't call `prepare()` directly after `stop()`. You have to reset the audio source and other parameters. See the state diagram in the linked documentation. It shows the steps you'll have to go through each time.

Comment: Hello Geobits, I actually modified my code and instead of preparing again the camera I call again the class by using Intent.  Yes it works.  But every time I clicked the stop button the screen creates a new Intent.  What I want is when I click the stop button the camera will just refresh like back to its prepare().  Is that possible?  thanks

Answer (score -1):

This one Geobits

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
    case 0:
       //start the recorder
       recorder.start();
       startedRecording=true;
       break;

    case 1: 
       //stop the recorder
       recorder.stop();
       recorder.prepare();
       startedRecording=false;
       break;


   default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```